# Laravel controllers not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm learning laravel but it isn't working out that well....
I've set my route in routes.php:

```
Route::get('/','WelcomeController@index');
```

Then I obviously have made a controller called "WelcomeController" and it looks like this:

```
<?php
class WelcomeController extends BaseController
{
 public function index() 
 {
    return view ('index');
 }

}
?>
```

And then I've made a view called index with just some html text.

But when I go to localhost/public I receive the error:

```
FatalErrorException in WelcomeController.php line 3:
Class 'BaseController' not found
```

And when I say:

```
class WelcomeController extends Illuminate\Routing\Controller
```

It does not work!

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Looks to me like you missed to declare the namespace your controller is in. At least if you follow the default structure that is. Add `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` at the top of your file.

Comment: thankyou it works now. But when I add another route "Contact" it's not found in localhost/public/contact ? But I'm doing it exactly the same?

Comment: Try `localhost/public/index.php/contact`. If that works, you have a htaccess problem...

Comment: THANKSS, That works. But how Can I fix the htacces problem?

Comment: Make sure htaccess is enabled. (`AllowOverride All`) I'm sure you'll find something on google if you need more help with that...

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it and works now.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
```

at the top of your controller file. That acts as an import

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now it's telling me:"ReflectionException in Container.php line 736:
Class App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Run `php composer dump-autoload` to make sure the class mappings is fresh.
2. Add `use Controller;` in your use block. The  modify your controller to extend it. Example:

`class WelcomeController extends Controller {...`

`Controller` is an interface in Laravel 4.*

In Laravel 5 use instead:
`use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` according to the documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers

Comment: I"ve added the "use" and updated everything with composer but still not working?

Comment: Now it's saying: Class App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController does not exist

Comment: It seems your app believes your controller is in the App\Http\Controllers namespace. Make sure the namespaces are corectly declared.